# Exception:Failed to convert parameter value from a Guid to a String

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a problem while creating a web application using LinqTemplate here is the explanation step wise....

1. I have created a database with a table name UserTest with one column name UserId with uniqidentifier datatype
2. I have created a classLiberary Project where i have used LinqTemplate of subsonic for code Generation of DAL and created a partial class for UserTest

   ```
   public partial class TestUser:Classes
   {
       public int Insert(TestUser user)
       {
         NFSLicensingSystemDB db = new NFSLicensingSystemDB();
         return  db.Insert.Into<TestUser>
              ( 
              x => x.UserId

              )
           .Values(
             user.UserId
           ).Execute();
       }

   }
   ```
3. I have created a web project in same solution and created a page UserTest.aspx with a button
   UserTest.aspx code for the page:-

   ```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
       <head runat="server">
           <title>Untitled Page</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <form id="form1" runat="server">
           <div>
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
           </div>
           </form>
       </body>
    </html>
   ```

4.UserTest.aspx.cs
Here Database is a connection String Name code for OnButton Click event

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Datadase.TestUser test =new Datadase.TestUser();
        test.UserId = Guid.NewGuid();
        test.Insert(test);

    }
```

Now when I Build the project it build successfully and when i run the project it shows
the UserTest.aspx page with a button but when i click on button it must insert the new guid value into the table but
it throws an exception

```
[InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.]
   System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) +2560525
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType) +414

[InvalidCastException: Failed to convert parameter value from a Guid to a String.]
  TestPages.UserEdit.btnCreateNewAccount_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\TestPages\UserEdit.aspx.cs:61
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +105
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check your class library, because it looks like its failing because the property "UserId" in class "Datadase.TestUser" is a string, not a Guid.

Comment: Hi Patrick,
Thanks for your reply. I am not Getting any solution for it and my work is stuck due to this .
This is a code in DAL class i am sure that it is of type Guid not a string ,so can You Give me another Solution.

Comment: namespace Datadase
{public partial class TestUser: INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged{
partial void OnLoaded();
partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
partial void OnCreated();
public TestUser(){OnCreated();}
partial void OnUserIdChanging(Guid value);
partial void OnUserIdChanged();
private Guid _UserId;
public Guid UserId {get{return _UserId;} 
set{this.OnUserIdChanging(value);
this.SendPropertyChanging();
this._UserId = value;
this.SendPropertyChanged("UserId");
                this.OnUserIdChanged();
      }
  }
}